# exception fired in iis but not in visal studio or my local iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

the problem i deployed an asp mvc web application in a server it fire some exception but in local iis or my visual studio not.

kind of exception:

```
     //the excpetion in this:

      DateTime date_deb = DateTime.ParseExact(_date_deb, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
     DateTime date_fin = DateTime.ParseExact(_date_fin, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);

     [FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]
     System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi,    
     DateTimeStyles style) +3200706
     System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider) +31



    //other exception here



    IList<object[]> bilansMois = session.CreateSQLQuery(sql).List<object[]>();
     bilansMois[0].Count() != 0


    [ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less 
     than the size of the collection.

     Parameter name: index]
     System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException() +72
      System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index) +9593284
```

thank you a lot

Comment: In the `Debug` menu in Visual Studio click `Exceptions` and check `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`.

Comment: Well the exception says the `DateTime` is not valid, so try using [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) and handle the error case.

Comment: Is there any chance you could get the date that it is trying to parse? I would put this down to localisation problems.

Comment: DateTime.TryParseExact yes ok but still the second error : thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use culture information as follow. Its because of server localization settings.

```
DateTime date_deb = DateTime.ParseExact(_date_deb, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime date_fin = DateTime.ParseExact(_date_fin, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For your second exception , Please check for NULL

```
if(bilansMois!=null)
     //DO your logic //
```

Comment: is there any problem in iis installation